# Dagger2 and Kotlin run failed cause by :app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to implement Dagger 2 in a test app to learn Clean Architecture and dependancy injection in Kotlin language.

> **EDIT :**
> I can compile thanks to @Logain, but I have always the static member problem with Dagger in my singleton (see below my *TaskWorker*), so I'm looking for how can I fix this error

But i got a problem, my DaggerComponent is well generated when i do a *rebuild*, but not when i want to run my app for testing, it fails and disappears. It fails with this error :

> Error:(21, 29) Unresolved reference: DaggerInjectorComponent
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava'.
>
> > Compilation error. See log for more details

While when i do a rebuild, this task is passed correctly

```
:app:compileDebugKotlinAfterJava
```

So i don't understand why it fails.

Here is my **InjectorComponent** :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ContextDaggerModule::class, LocalStoreDaggerModule::class))
interface InjectorComponent {

    fun inject(realmLocalStore: RealmLocalStore)

    fun inject(taskWorker: TaskWorker)

}
```

**ContectDaggerModule** :

```
@Module
class ContextDaggerModule (val app: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideResources(): Resources = app.resources

}
```

**LocalStoreDaggerModule** :

```
@Module
class LocalStoreDaggerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLocalStore(context: Context): LocalStore {
        return RealmLocalStore(context)
    }

}
```

I think the problem is caused because I inject dependencies in [Object-declarations](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) but all elements are static and Dagger does not appreciate it.
So, i try to hack it with a simple override getter and injecting data but nop.

Here is my "hack" :

```
object TaskWorker {

    // @Inject lateinit var localStore: LocalStore
    // Not work cause it's a static variable

    var localStore: LocalStore? = null
        @Inject
        get() = localStore

    // some cool function
}
```

I follow this [code](https://github.com/juanchosaravia/KedditBySteps) and this [tutorial](http://www.andevcon.com/news/keddit-part-10-kotlin-dagger-2-dependency-injection)

I use these dependencies :

```
//  Dagger2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Comment: Try marking `localStore` as `@JvmField`. If it won't work then run `gradlew build --debug --stacktrace` and paste the stacktrace

Comment: @Mibac I cannot apply this annotation cause my `localStore` has a custom getter

Comment: Could you create another variable (and put the `@JvmField` as well as `@Inject` annotations on it) or delete the custom getter to test if the getter is the problem?
if not then please run gradle with `--debug --stacktrace` arguments so we can see what the exception is

Comment: @Mibac i tried too, but same things, cannot work, because inject in variable needs a `lateinit var` and `@JvmField` cannot annotate a lateinit field

Comment: Then run gradle with `build --debug --stacktrace` and paste the stacktrace so we can see what the error is

Comment: @Mibac I also tried without `lateinit` but compiler and dagger does not appreciate that

Comment: Ok I got this info : `TaskWorker cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147826/discussion-between-mrleblond-and-mibac).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using:

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Due to some [limitations on kapt](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/)

Or just try with:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
```

Comment: Yes I'm using kapt, but i had forgotten this annotationProcessor.

Comment: But my "hack" to inject in static var by overriding getter not work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this.

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Just apply the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and add the dependencies:

```
compile androidDependencies.dagger2
compile androidDependencies.dagger2Android
kapt androidDependencies.dagger2Kapt
```

sometimes the tasks fail with errors like that. Try to `clean` and as last resort use `invalidate and restart`. Most of the times it works.